# Update Entity property in EF where property is another entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 and I need to update the properties of a entity.

I have the following entities:

```
public class File 
{
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Byte Data { get; set; }
  public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
  public virtual Mime Mime { get; set; }
}
public class Mime 
{
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Then I used the following:

```
_repository.Update<File>(file, x => x.Data, x => x.Mime, x => x.Updated);
```

The repository method is the following:

```
public void Update<T>(T entity,
                      params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] properties)
                      where T : class 
{

  _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);

  foreach (var property in properties) 
  {
    MemberExpression expression =
                     property.Body is MemberExpression ? 
                     (MemberExpression)property.Body : 
                     (MemberExpression)(((UnaryExpression)property.Body)
                                                                  .Operand);
    _context.Entry<T>(entity)
            .Property(expression.Member.Name).IsModified = true;
  }
}
```

This works fine for `Data` and Updated properties but not for `Mime`. I get the error:

> The property 'Mime' on type 'File' is not a primitive or complex property. The Property method can only be used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method.

Is it possible to make this work and integrate it on my repository method?

Comment: First question is: why do you have this elaborate `Update` method? Why can't you leave it to EF's change tracker to mark properties as modified? What's the bigger picture?

Comment: The File entity has a property Data which can be kind of big because it holds a file ... So I would like to update some fields without loading the data into memory. Does this make sense? This worked when I do not have entities related with it.

Comment: You should take a look at *table splitting*.

Comment: Yes, I have splited tables ... This is the file table and I want to update the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that can be done. The problem here is that I didn't see any easy way to check **whenever a property is part of the table, or is it navigational property.** Thus it's hard to call the right behavior.

If you're interested, take a look at EF6 source code, `InternalEntityEntry.cs` -> `Property(..)` which does huge amount of property validation through metadata.

The main idea is to basically scan your conceptual model, and determine whenever the property is navigational property(eg if the property leads to another table), or if it's complex/primitive.

According to that, you call the right functionality.

```
var propertyName = expression.Member.Name;                                              
var propertyType = __get_property_type__(propertyName);

if(propertyType==Property || propertyType==Complex)
{
    _context.Entry<T>(entity)
        .Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;

    continue;
}

if(propertyType==Navigational){

    // hm, do we need Attach it first?!
    // not sure.. have to test first.
    dynamic underlyingReference = entity.GetType()
            .GetProperty(propertyName)
            .GetValue(entity, null);

    _context.Entry(underlyingReference).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

The catch here is to have `__get_property_type__` that works. There's   [Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.edm.library.edmentitytype(v=vs.113).aspx) that let's you work with the conceptual model, but it's not that easy I think.

This is the way how EF6 detects if we're dealing with reference property or not:

```
EdmMember member;
EdmEntityType.Members.TryGetValue(propertyName, false, out member);

var asNavProperty = member as NavigationProperty;
// if asNavProperty!=null, we have navigation property.
```

Answer (score -2):

100% Gerts point.  I see no reason to approach the problem they way you have.
Anyway, to answer the question.  You have another answer there. Potentially useful.

Whats missing is this:

How to get a list of managed types from the context.

```
    public static  IList<Type> GetContextManagedTypes(DbContext context) {
        ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        IEnumerable<EntityType> managedTypes = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);

        var typeList = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var managedType in managedTypes) {
            var pocoType = managedType.FullName.GetCoreType();
            typeList.Add(pocoType);
        }

        return typeList;
    }
```